# Cygwin: Safe to `cp Some/File.txt /dev/clipboard`?

Tags: cygwin, clipboard

I know that there is putlcip and getclip, but sometimes, I just want to deal with files.  I know that I can `cp` from `/dev/clipboard` to another file, and the result is a text file with the same permissions as `/dev/clipboard`.

**Is it safe to issue the command `cp Some/File.txt /dev/clipboard`?**

I don't want to try it in case I overwrite `/dev/clipboard` in unintended ways, e.g., turn it from a device into a regular text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/clipboard is a special cygwin file.
If you look with explorer the dev directory it does NOT exist in Windows.

```
cat Some/File.txt > /dev/clipboard
```

works fine and similar with cp

Comment: Thanks for that. I do wonder, though, what was your backup plan if your attempt at the above command has clobbered `/dev/clipboard` and made it into something other than the special Cygwin file that it is?

Comment: It is not too difficult to reinstall any package ;-) and I already know something about Cygwin https://cygwin.com/who.html

Comment: I know something about it too, but not what package sets up `/dev/clipboard`. A package search for `/dev/clipboard` turns up nothing, while a search for `clipboard` turns up too much . A google search for `/dev/clipboard site:www.cygwin.com` turns up postings rather than packages.  That's why I was wondering what your recovery strategy was.  I would have guessed that `/dev/clipboard` would be set up by the base Cygwin installation.

Comment: `/dev` devices  are virtual creations of the cygwin1.dll

Comment: Doesn't that mean re-installing a core component of Cygwin?  It's still just a matter of selecting re-install in the installer?  I'm guessing so, as surprising as that seems.  After all, cygwin is presumably offline (not being used) during the re-install.

Comment: I mean as the clipboard is a virtual creation and not a real file/object you can not 'overwrite' it. Of course the harddisks '/dev/sdxx' are a different matter as they are a interface to a real object and you can destroy them.

Comment: Ah, OK.  That's useful to know.  And yes, this is completely in line fact that it does not exist in Windows Explorer.  Thanks!